# MD5 hash With ftplib

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, md5, ftplib

```
>>>import ftplib 
>>>import hashlib

>>>ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost','username','password')
>>>ftp.cwd('Server')
'250 Directory successfully changed.'
>>>m=hashlib.md5()
>>> file = open('Desktop/space.png','rb')
>>> m.update("space.png")
>>> dd = m.hexdigest()
>>> dd
'f646cdee237bd84e33485eb03c9228ac'
>>> ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd, file)
'226 Transfer complete.'
>>> file.close()
>>> ftp.quit()
'221 Goodbye.'
>>>
```

How to store different hexadecimal digits file? As this Python code keep storing the same hexadecimal digits file. Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 of `"space.png"` will always be `f646cdee237bd84e33485eb03c9228ac`. You don't explain what you're trying to do exactly. If you're trying to use unique filenames which are MD5 hashes, you can try something like this.

```
import uuid
m.update(str(uuid.uuid4()))
dd = m.hexdigest()
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd, file)
```

`uuid.uuid4()` will generate a universally unique identifier whose MD5 hash will practically be unique.

Comment: So there is no way "space.png" be another hexadecimal digits with md5 hash?

Comment: A MD5 is a unique value for all (practical) input data. Since you're always passing `space.png`, you'll always get same hex digits. If you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve by doing that, I might be able to help you.

Comment: i wanted to  do is every time i store the same file "space.png" into the server, it will generate another hex decimal.